# Syntax Error in SQL Select statement with Case (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the written following query but it i am getting an error message
i.e `FROM KEY WORD NOT FOUND`

Any idea?

```
SELECT H.AGG_HEADER_SEQ,
   H.PRICE,
   D.AGG_DETAIL_SEQ,
   D.MONEY_UNITS,
   D.CASH_VALUE,
   D.UNIT_VALUE,
   D.MONEY_UNITS_VALUE,
   CASE
      WHEN D.MONEY_UNITS = 'U' THEN (D.UNIT_VALUE * H.PRICE) / 1
      WHEN D.MONEY_UNITS = 'M' THEN D.UNIT_VALUE
      ELSE 0
   END
      AS CASH_VALUE_CALC INTO CAL_CASH_VALUE,
   CASE
      WHEN D.MONEY_UNITS = 'U' THEN D.CASH_VALUE
      WHEN D.MONEY_UNITS = 'M' THEN (D.CASH_VALUE * H.PRICE) / 1
      ELSE 0
   END
      AS UNIT_VALUE_CALC INTO CAL_UNIT_VALUE
   FROM FCS.ORDTRAN_NOM_AGG_HEADER H
   JOIN FCS.ORDTRAN_NOM_AGG_DETAIL D
      ON H.AGG_HEADER_SEQ = D.AGG_HEADER_SEQ
   WHERE H.AGG_HEADER_SEQ = 5379 AND D.ALLOW_PRICING = 'Y';
```

Comment: Is this being run inside a PL/SQL block? The `into` clauses are only valid in PL/SQL; and then you'd need a single clause, and variable targets for all the selected columns, not just the two you've already aliased? If not then I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with them.

Comment: Try removing the `INTO XXX` expressions

Comment: Are you sure you need those `INTO` clauses?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get rid of `INTO CAL_CASH_VALUE`:

```
SELECT H.AGG_HEADER_SEQ,
   H.PRICE,
   D.AGG_DETAIL_SEQ,
   D.MONEY_UNITS,
   D.CASH_VALUE,
   D.UNIT_VALUE,
   D.MONEY_UNITS_VALUE,
   CASE
      WHEN D.MONEY_UNITS = 'U' THEN (D.UNIT_VALUE * H.PRICE) / 1
      WHEN D.MONEY_UNITS = 'M' THEN D.UNIT_VALUE
      ELSE 0
   END
      AS CASH_VALUE_CALC INTO CAL_CASH_VALUE,
   CASE
      WHEN D.MONEY_UNITS = 'U' THEN D.CASH_VALUE
      WHEN D.MONEY_UNITS = 'M' THEN (D.CASH_VALUE * H.PRICE) / 1
      ELSE 0
   END
      AS UNIT_VALUE_CALC INTO CAL_UNIT_VALUE
   FROM FCS.ORDTRAN_NOM_AGG_HEADER H
   JOIN FCS.ORDTRAN_NOM_AGG_DETAIL D
      ON H.AGG_HEADER_SEQ = D.AGG_HEADER_SEQ
   WHERE H.AGG_HEADER_SEQ = 5379 AND D.ALLOW_PRICING = 'Y';
```

If you want to use this query for PL/SQL you have to put this right above the `FROM` clause, but you have to add variables for other fields.